# ¿Seleccionar contenido del <body> exceptuando ciertos elementos mediante jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

De nuevo por acá. Mi menú ya puede bajar y verse muy bien. Esta vez lo que necesito es que cuando el mouse **NO** este en cualquiera de las partes del menú, desaparezca, es decir, cuando el usuario lleve el mouse a cualquier otra parte de la pagina que no sea el menú, el menú debería hacer un *slide up*. Mi problema esta en el selector de **jQuery**, que no consigo afinar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".level1-option").hover(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideDown();
    });

    $("body div").not(".header-menu, .level1-option, .sub-menu1-container, .sub-menu1-img, .sub-menu1-options, .sub-menu2-options").mouseenter(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideUp();
    });

});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 background: white;
 height: 147px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 100;
}

.header-menu {
 color: grey; 
 position: absolute; 
 right: 100px; 
 bottom: 20px;
}

.level1-option {
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: grey;
}

.level1-option:hover {
 color: #e6b800;
 cursor: all-scroll;
}

.sub-menu1-container {
 margin: 0 5%;
 background: white;
 height: 337px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
}

.sub-menu1-img {
 padding: 1% 10%;
 position: absolute;
}

.sub-menu1-options {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 background: #e6e5e5;
 position: absolute; 
 left: 55%;
 height: 337px;
 width: 45%;
}

.sub-menu2-options {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 background: #c1bebe;
 position: absolute; 
 left: 70%;
 height: 337px;
 width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="level1-option">option 1</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 2</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 3</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 4</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 5</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu1-container" hidden>
  <div class="sub-menu1-img">
    <img src="http://www.ikea.com/PIAimages/0324126_PE517034_S5.JPG" style="width: 300px; height: 320px;">
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu1-options">

  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu2-options">

  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactamente que quieres lograr, no te entiendo

Comment: @CamiloVasquez quiero que el menu se esconda cuando voy a cualquier otra parte de mi pagina, eso es todo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el evento `mouseover` del `body` y evitar la propagación de este evento en los elementos en los que no quieras que se repliegue el menú:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".level1-option").hover(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideDown();
    });
    $("body").mouseover(function() {$(".sub-menu1-container").slideUp(); });
    $(".header-menu").mouseover(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });

});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 background: white;
 height: 147px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 100;
}

.header-menu {
 color: grey; 
 position: absolute; 
 right: 100px; 
 bottom: 20px;
}

.level1-option {
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: grey;
}

.level1-option:hover {
 color: #e6b800;
 cursor: all-scroll;
}

.sub-menu1-container {
 margin: 0 5%;
 background: white;
 height: 337px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
}

.sub-menu1-img {
 padding: 1% 10%;
 position: absolute;
}

.sub-menu1-options {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 background: #e6e5e5;
 position: absolute; 
 left: 55%;
 height: 337px;
 width: 45%;
}

.sub-menu2-options {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 background: #c1bebe;
 position: absolute; 
 left: 70%;
 height: 337px;
 width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="level1-option">option 1</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 2</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 3</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 4</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 5</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu1-container" hidden>
  <div class="sub-menu1-img">
    <img src="http://www.ikea.com/PIAimages/0324126_PE517034_S5.JPG" style="width: 300px; height: 320px;">
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu1-options">

  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu2-options">

  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```